# SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH = next month at today

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a small and lightweight PHP based work table system. I know on net I can find many, but these are so overdozed to me.

I have table with:

```
ID
date
user_name
workplace1_am
workplace1_pm
workplace2_am
workplace2_pm
```

For current month and current date I solved problem.

Now I need to get data from the table only for next month:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...
```

Comment: Post your attempts...

Comment: Actually i dont have these, because dont have any idea, how to do this. And thanks about good correction, next time i know now!

Comment: EDIT: I forgot inform, that my date inside table is on 20140901 format, Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good example is to make sure your month column is a `DATE()` so cast it to a date,
then compare to the `CURDATE()` which pulls out a date. `NOW()` pulls out the date and the time which won't work when comparing to a date.

```
SELECT whatever_you_need
FROM table
WHERE date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

NOTE: I don't recommend you just pull everything out with a `SELECT *`, you should always pull out the specific rows you need

#### EDIT:

to find for a year and month you could do this

```
SELECT whatever_you_need
FROM table
WHERE EXTRACT(year_month FROM date) = EXTRACT(year_month FROM CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ef59e/4)

year_month returns data in yyyymm format so it is a unique comparison by month and year in one function call

Comment: You probably mean `CURDATE`.

Comment: @MateuszNowak yup was already fixing it :)

Comment: Thank you! I found that had mistake on my sql and date column not marked as DATE. After your hint i got it working finally.

Answer (score 5):

#### With `date` field

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE month = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

#### With `timestamp` field

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: With this: `SELECT * FROM list_shifts WHERE MONTH(date)` i get current month data. I forgot inform, that my date inside table is on 20140901 format, Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

> Use this

```
SELECT DATE_ADD($currentdate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

> Refer this very useful [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)